# Check if it's possible to arrange strings in a way that each consecutive pair of strings differ by 1 character

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, logic

Given an array of equal-length strings, you'd like to know if it's possible to rearrange the order of the elements in such a way that each consecutive pair of strings differ by exactly one character. Return `true` if it's possible, and `false` if not.

Note: You're only rearranging the order of the strings, not the order of the letters within the strings!

Example

- For `inputArray = ["aba", "bbb", "bab"]`, the output should be:

  **solution(inputArray) = false.**

There are 6 possible arrangements for these strings:

```
   * ["aba", "bbb", "bab"]
   * ["aba", "bab", "bbb"]
   * ["bbb", "aba", "bab"]
   * ["bbb", "bab", "aba"]
   * ["bab", "bbb", "aba"]
   * ["bab", "aba", "bbb"]
```

None of these satisfy the condition of consecutive strings differing by 1 character, so the answer is false.

- For `inputArray = ["ab", "bb", "aa"]`, the output should be:

  **solution(inputArray) = true.**

It's possible to arrange these strings in a way that each consecutive pair of strings differ by 1 character (eg: `"aa", "ab", "bb"` or `"bb", "ab", "aa"`), so return true.

Comment: What have you tried yourself?  Where has it failed?  Please review [ask] in the [help].  I have a technique I'm willing to share, but not unless you demonstrate more effort of your own.

Comment: Hi @ScottSauyet . My plan was to get an array (2D) with all the different and possible sequences and then check if each one satisfies the condition. but I have thought and thought and I don't know how to take the first step. Trust me I just want an answer to see how it could have been fixed so I can learn from someone better. I have already passed almost 100 tests on that website, if I ask it is because I really have no idea.

Comment: Have you looked up [permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) or how to do them [in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+permutations)?  That should give you a good start at the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the algorithm could be described as follows

1. Write a function which counts the differences between two strings (`difCount()`)
2. Compare every pair of strings (i.e., 1 with 2, 1 with 3, 2 with 3) to check that all strings has a "friend" which differs only by 1 char.
3. If there's at least one string that hasn't got a pair, the test fails.

```js
arr =  ["ff", "gf", "af", "ar", "hf"];

// count how many letters are differnt between two strings
function difCount(str1, str2){
  dif_count = 0;
  [...str1].map((val, ind) => {
     // val != str2[ind] is comparison between the chars in the neighboring strings at the same indexes (i.e. first with first, second with second)
     // if comparison passes, then it is 1, so dif_count (which counts the differences) increments, otherwise it doesn't increment
     dif_count += val != str2[ind];
  })
  return dif_count;
}

// create array of zeros with the length of arr.length
checks = Array(arr.length).fill(0);

// below we compare each element with every another element.
//If there's a pair of strings str1 and str2 with the difference of 1 character, we set the corresponding indexes in "checks" array to 1.
//If the "checks" array contains all 1's then all the strings have pairs, otherwise test fails.
//If array contains duplicates, then test fails

dupes = 0;

arr.map((str1, ind1) => {
  arr.map((str2, ind2) => {
     if(difCount(str1, str2) == 1){
        checks[ind1] = 1;
        checks[ind2] = 1;
     }
     if(str1 == str2 && ind1 != ind2) dupes = 1;
  }) 
})

// So, if there're no dupes and no zeros in the checks array, then the test has passed

pass = !dupes && !checks.includes(0) ? "pass" : "fail";

console.log(pass)
```

Comment: Almost done! you code pass 8/11 test. the code fail on:                                                      
 1- inputArray: ["q", "q"] -- Output:: true. -- Expected Output:  false                                                                                                                       2- inputArray: ["abc",  "abx",  "axx",  "abc"] -- Output: true. --  Expected Output: false.                                                                                                      3- inputArray: ["ff", "gf",  "af",  "ar",  "hf"] -- Output: false. --Expected Output: true.

Comment: And sorry, but i Don't understand this part:      dif_count += val != (r = str2[ind]);

Comment: @J.Villasmil These errors come up from my non-understanding of the question, I guess. Was the task saying "exactly 1 difference" or "at most 1 difference" (that means no difference or 1 char diference)?

Comment: It should return true if it differs by exactly one character, no more and no less. This problem has me stuck!

Comment: @J.Villasmil I believe I addressed all the problems, please check the answer again. I updated the algorithm and provided an explanation for your second comment.

Comment: You passed  ["q", "q"] but the other two still haven't. I think it may be because of the sequence in which each string is being compared. look at the different ways to order the same array in example 1 of my question: for each version one string is compared with the next and so on. link of the problem: https://app.codesignal.com/arcade/intro/level-7/PTWhv2oWqd6p4AHB9

Comment: @J.Villasmil how doesn't it pass the other two? in my example the array is  ["ff", "gf", "af", "ar", "hf"]  and it's a pass

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243392/discussion-between-j-villasmil-and-nicael).

Comment: I was wrong, ["ff", "gf", "af", "ar", "hf"] passed,  the bug is now number two of my first comment and ["ab", "ad", "ef" , "e.g"].  Output: true Expected Output: false

Comment: Suppose the strings were `['ab', 'ac', 'ad', 'pq', 'pr', 'ps']`. All these strings have a "friend" but `false` is to be returned. Each string having a "friend" is a necessary, but not sufficient, condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
function solution(inputArray) {
    var possible = false;

    // helper function to check permutations of the input array
    var permute = function (arr, m = []) {
        if (arr.length === 0) {
            // iterate through all permutations and check for a single character difference
            for (var i = 0; i < m.length - 1; i++) {
                var diff = 0;
                for (var j = 0; j < m[i].length; j++) {
                    if (m[i][j] !== m[i + 1][j]) {
                        diff++;
                    }
                }
                // if more than one character difference, return
                if (diff !== 1) {
                    return;
                }
            }
            possible = true;
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                var curr = arr.slice();
                var next = curr.splice(i, 1);
                permute(curr.slice(), m.concat(next));
            }
        }
    };
    // call permute function to check all permutations
    permute(inputArray);
    return possible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to understand the question by just following the logic inside the description. So the solution could be implemented by just three steps: 1. Find out all the permutations of the inputArray; 2. Generate a function that can count the amount of different letters between any two consecutive strings; 3. Check each row inside the rearranged array.

```
function solution(inputArray) {
    // Generate all permutations of the input array
    const rearrangedArrs = permute(inputArray);
    
    // Compare consecutive strings in each row 
    for (let row = 0; row < rearrangedArrs.length; row++) {
        let foundBreak = true;
        for (let col = 0; col < rearrangedArrs[0].length-1; col++) {
            // Find the difference between consecutive strings 
            const charDiff = findDiff(rearrangedArrs[row][col], rearrangedArrs[row][col+1]);
            if(charDiff.length !== 1) {
               foundBreak = false;
               break;
            }
        }
        if(foundBreak === true) return true;
    }   // end outer loop
    return false;
}

// A helper function that counts how many letters are different
// between two strings
function findDiff(str1, str2) {
    let diff = '';
    str2.split('').forEach((val, idx) => {
        if(val != str1.charAt(idx)) diff += val;
    })
    return diff;
}

// A function that generates all permutations of an array of strings
function permute(strings) {
    let result = [];
    // base case
    if (strings.length === 0) return [];
    if (strings.length === 1) return [strings];
    
    // For each element in the input array, create a new 
    // array with the remaining elements and generate all
    // permutations of that array recursively
    for (let i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
        const currentStr = strings[i];
        const remainingStrs = strings.slice(0, i).concat(strings.slice(i + 1));
        const remainingStrsPermuted = permute(remainingStrs);
        
        // For each permutation of the remaining strings, 
        // add the current string to the beginning and create
        // a new array
        for (let j = 0; j < remainingStrsPermuted.length; j++) {
            const permutedArray =  [currentStr].concat(remainingStrsPermuted[j]);
            
            result.push(permutedArray);
        }
     }  // end outer loop
    
    return result;
}
```

If you want to know more about how to find differences between two arbitrary strings, please read the following article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Answer (score 0):

Create a graph with an edge between each pair of valid strings and then find out if there exists a hamiltonian path in the formed graph.

Answer (score 0):

My solution can pass all the test case in codesignal. The ideal is try to form a sequence that is consecutive, if the result is empty, then means no solution available.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

bool is_one_digit_diff(const std::string& str1, const std::string& str2) {
    int diffCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str1.size(); ++i) {
        if (str1[i] != str2[i]) {
            diffCount += 1;
            if (diffCount > 1) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return diffCount == 1;
}

std::vector<std::vector<int>> appendNextConsecutive(const std::vector<std::string>& vec_string, const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& consec_sequences) {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> next_consecutive;
    for (int i = 0; i < vec_string.size(); ++i) {
        for (auto sequence : consec_sequences) {
            if (std::find(sequence.begin(), sequence.end(), i) != sequence.end()) {
                continue;
            }
            if (is_one_digit_diff(vec_string[sequence.back()], vec_string[i])) {
                sequence.push_back(i);
                next_consecutive.push_back(sequence);
            }
        }
    }
    return next_consecutive;
}

static bool solution(std::vector<std::string> vec_string) {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> consec_sequences;
    int currentLength = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < vec_string.size(); ++i) {
        std::vector<int> sequence{i};
        consec_sequences.push_back(sequence);
    }

    while (!consec_sequences.empty() && consec_sequences.front().size() < vec_string.size()) {
        consec_sequences = appendNextConsecutive(vec_string, consec_sequences);
    }

    return !consec_sequences.empty();
}

void TestArrangeStringToBeConsecutive() {
    {
        std::vector<std::string> vec_string{ "abc", "bef", "bcc", "bec", "bbc", "bdc" };
        const bool result = solution(vec_string);
        std::cout << "Result " << result << std::endl;
        assert(result == true);
    }

    {
        std::vector<std::string> vec_string{ "abc", "abx", "axx", "abc" };
        const bool result = solution(vec_string);
        std::cout << "Result " << result << std::endl;
        assert(result == false);
    }

    {
        std::vector<std::string> vec_string{ "zzzabzczaaa", "zzzabzczaaa", "zzzabzczaaa", "zzzabzczaaa" };
        const bool result = solution(vec_string);
        std::cout << "Result " << result << std::endl;
        assert(result == false);
    }

    {
        std::vector<std::string> vec_string{ "abc", "xbc", "xxc", "xbc", "aby", "ayy", "aby" };
        const bool result = solution(vec_string);
        std::cout << "Result " << result << std::endl;
        assert(result == true);
    }
}
```